# 16*2 LCD display doesn't display my result

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd

I am working on a project to calculate line frequency meter by reciprocal counting with Arduino. I am trying to print the the result on a 16*2 LCD but it is not displaying anything. It just gets on and stuck there. I got the project details from this website [Line Frequency Meter Based On Reciprocal Counting](https://electronicsforu.com/electronics-projects/line-frequency-meter-reciprocal-counting)

I modified the stock program to interface the LCD but it's not working. Here is the code I am using:

```
//To read and display the Line frequency 
//using Reciprocal counting method
//clk for 'Time Counter'  is generated with 'Tone' function 
//'Time counter' is the physical counter T1
// 'EVENT Counter' is a software counter
#define Fin 6      // input pin for Line freq sig
#define clk 7      // input to ' Time ' counter
#include<LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
boolean FState;   // status of the 50 Hz Signal 
int countS;       // Signal count
int countC=0;     //  Clock count
int LineFreq;     // Result

void setup() {
  tone(8, 5000); // generates ref freq of 5000 Hz at Pin 8
  pinMode(Fin, INPUT); // set the Fin pin as INPUT
  pinMode(clk, INPUT); // set the clk pin as INPUT
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop() {  
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Frequency of signal");       
  // to avoid partial cycles, first detect the rising edge
  while(digitalRead(Fin)) {
    //wait for '0' state of the Signal
    delayMicroseconds(10);
  }
  //here '0' state
  while(!digitalRead(Fin)) {
    //wait for '1' state
    delayMicroseconds(10);
  }
  //this is the rising edge of the Fin
  //counting can start from here
  // clear the TIME Counter T1
  counterStart1();
  //count 50 of the Line freq signals
  while(countS<50) {
    while(digitalRead(Fin)) {
      //wait for '0' state
      delayMicroseconds(1);
    }    
    //here '0' state
    while(!digitalRead(Fin)) {
      //wait for '1' state
      delayMicroseconds(1);
    }
    // here '1' state
    // here one cycle is just over
    //increment the event counter
    countS=countS+1;
  }
  //here 50 Signal cycles over
  // read the contents of T1 & compute frequency
  countC = getCount1();
  LineFreq = 25000000/countC;

  //send to display
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(LineFreq);
  lcd.print(" Hz");
  delay(500);  
  delay(100);
  // clear counter
  countS=0;
  // repeat
}

//The following code is obtained from on-line articles in the public domain
void counterStart1() {
 // hardware counter setup,  for  the 16-bit Timer1 Timer/Counter
 TCCR1A=0; // reset timer/countern control register A
 TCCR1B=0; // reset timer/countern control register B
 TCNT1=0; // initialize the counter value to 0; this register holds the current count
  // set timer/counter1 hardware as a counter; it counts events on pin Tn (Arduino pin 5)
 TCCR1B = TCCR1B | 7; // Counter Clock source = pin Tn (Arduino pin 5) , start counting now
 // 7 in binary is 0111; OR-ing will set CS10,11,12 to 1's
return;
}

// the following code is obtained from on-line articles in the public domain
// Sub routine  to get the current count
unsigned int getCount1() {
 unsigned int count; // this variable returns the current count from the counting register
 TCCR1B = TCCR1B & ~7; // Gate Off  / Counter T1 stopped, 
 // this operation clears the bits (CS10,11,12)
 count = TCNT1; // read the counting register
 TCCR1B = TCCR1B | 7; // re-start counting by resetting the bits (CS10,11,12)
 return count; // return the retrieved count to the calling function
}
```

I am getting a blank screen but the line at very first of the code "Frequency of signal" is printing accurately.

What is wrong with the code and what changes do I need?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which is it? Not displaying anything, or only displaying "Frequency of signal"?

Comment: I fixed your indentation, as it was nearly impossible to read.

Comment: If the latter, it seems like you signal on pin 6 isn't there, or is too weak. Ending up with your code waiting for 50 transitions that just aren't there?

Comment: It is only displaying frequency of the signal only, which is written at the top of code. After that nothing is working. I checked the pin 6 signal And it was working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your variables are `int`, which on an Arduino is a 2-byte signed type by default, and has a range of `-32768` to `32767`.

When you execute:

```
LineFreq = 25000000/countC;
```

is the result of the math a 2-byte `int`, or a 4-byte `long`? Regardless, you are possibly assigning a 4-byte value to an `int`.

You can declare `LineFreq` to be type `long`, and also append an `L` to the end of the constant value `25000000` to force `long` math, so that you have:

```
long LineFreq;
[...]
LineFreq = 25000000L/countC;
```